# jQuery: select all elements of a given class, except for a particular Id

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This is probably pretty simple.

I want to select all elements of a given class `thisClass`, except where the id is `thisId`.

i.e. something equivalent to (where -/minus implies remove):

```
$(".thisClass"-"#thisId").doAction();
```

Answer (score 335, accepted):

Use the [**:not selector**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

```
$(".thisclass:not(#thisid)").doAction();
```

If you have multiple ids or selectors just use the comma delimiter, in addition:

`(".thisclass:not(#thisid,#thatid)").doAction();`

Comment: What if you want to exclude more than one classes?
THX

Comment: From the documentation: `All selectors are accepted inside :not(), for example: :not(div a) and :not(div,a)` so just use the comma delimited selectors to do multiple `(".thisclass:not(#thisid,#thatid)").doAction();`

Comment: worked with single quotes like this - $(".thisclass:not('#thisid')").doAction();

Comment: or if you want to bind to all child of elements that has a specific class name, except one, you can do like this:$('.thisclass:not(#id) .otherclass').doAction()

Comment: what if i have a standard code like: $('#some').notimportant,  $('#another').dosomethingelse and i want  to avoid execution over an specific id given dynamically?

Comment: How to combine it with `:last`? So `.thisclass:last:not(#thisid)` seems not to work.

Answer (score 35):

Or take the .not() method

https://api.jquery.com/not/

```
$(".thisClass").not("#thisId").doAction();
```

Comment: `.not()` isn't a selector. It's a function. But there is also `:not()` selector like other answer mentions.

Answer (score 10):

I'll just throw in a JS (ES6) answer, in case someone is looking for it:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".myClass:not(#myId)")).forEach((el,i) => {
    doSomething(el);
}
```

Update (this may have been possible when I posted the original answer, but adding this now anyway):

```
document.querySelectorAll(".myClass:not(#myId)").forEach((el,i) => {
    doSomething(el);
});
```

This gets rid of the `Array.from` usage.

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`.
Read here to know more about how to iterate on it (and other things): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Answer (score 8):

You could use the **.not** function like the following examples to remove items that have an exact id, id containing a specific word, id starting with a word, etc... see http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp for more information on jQuery selectors.

Ignore by Exact ID:

```
 $(".thisClass").not('[id="thisId"]').doAction();
```

Ignore ID's that contains the word "Id"

```
$(".thisClass").not('[id*="Id"]').doAction();
```

Ignore ID's that start with "my"

```
$(".thisClass").not('[id^="my"]').doAction();
```

Answer (score 5):

`$(".thisClass[id!='thisId']").doAction();`

Documentation on selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: did you mean $(".thisClass[id!='thisId']").doAction(); ?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `.not()` method with selecting an entire element is also an option.

This way could be usefull if you want to do another action with that element directly.

```js
$(".thisClass").not($("#thisId")[0].doAnotherAction()).doAction();
```