# Select everything in the parent except the child

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm writing a backbone app, and using the built-in event handling, which uses jquery selectors.

I'd like to write a selector which will select everything except the `.delete` below, and then a selector for `.delete` exclusively (which is a lot simpler.)

Basically, I'd like to select everything in the parent except this one specific child.

I tried `li:not(.delete)`, but that didn't work. Any ideas?

```
<li class="">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="icon-book"></i>
    <span class="name">@randallb</span>
    <i class="delete icon-remove-sign pull-right"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: There are 3 elements nested into `a` nested into `li`. Which actually you need to select?

Comment: Give this answer a try:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551217/jquery-select-all-elements-of-a-given-class-except-for-a-particular-id

Comment: @fguillen: jQuery selectors are different from CSS selectors. I was about to downvote all but one of the answers for seemingly answering a CSS question with JS code, but noticed that the original question was tagged [jquery]. jQuery does employ a selector engine to search DOM elements, so IMO the original tag is appropriate. To that end I've changed the tags back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('li > a *:not(.delete)')
```

Comment: This was what I actually ended up using because Backbone already assumes you're scoped into the li.

Answer (score 5):

```css
li :not(.delete)
```

The space is needed to specify descendants, without it the `not` operates on the `li` meaning selecting `li` that does not have the `delete` class

Comment: I gave this a quick try in a jsFiddle but it didn't seem to work. Am I doing it wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/ck2Mt/

Comment: Not just color, but all rules are inherited, which is how the cascade is meant to work. But I believe the original poster did not want the anchor element (which contains the other three) to be selected. On second read, I believe this meets the *literal* requirements of the question but I'm not sure it's what they actually need. I can't think of a real-world use case in which they would want the anchor selected as well.

Comment: @GregPettit many property rules aren't inherited, also cascading deals with rules overwriting others not inheritance.

Comment: The only property rules I can think of that aren't inherited are those that are not appropriate to the node type or those disallowed by the context (ie. positioning). Perhaps "all" was an overstatement. As for the cascade, inheritance and overwriting are simply two sides of the same coin. All "overwriting" means is that the property that would otherwise have been taken from another rule is instead taken from (inherited from) this more specific rule. Inheritance vs. overwriting is just semantics. Viewing it one way or the other is just a matter of which perspective works best for you.

Comment: @Greg Pettit: Whether or not a property is inherited by default is stated in the spec. And Musa is right: cascading and inheritance are two distinct concepts; while both are involved in computing a given style, they don't depend on each other. Either way, we're probably bordering the line of pedantry here...

Comment: I'm a pretty stubborn guy, but I think Musa's correct in this side debate after all. Regardless, I think this solves the OP's literal question but not their intended question. Clearly the anchor is also being selected, and any changes you might make to the group of nodes will create unexpected and unintended inheritance problems as a result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').children().find('*:not(.delete)').css('color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are looking for.

```
// allChildrenArray will hold all the children of li except .delete
   var allChildrenArray = [];
    function getSelectedChildren(parentContainer, rejectedClass){
        parentContainer.children().each(function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass(rejectedClass)){
                allChildrenArray.push(this);
            }
            getSelectedChildren($(this), rejectedClass);
        });
    }
    getSelectedChildren($('li'), 'delete');
```