# Can I use getElementById to select and hide content that does not have the id specified?

Tags: javascript, php

For example, I have this function.

```
function showprintdiv() {
    var x = document.getElementById('post-Print ');
    if (!x.style.display || x.style.display == 'block') {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'block';
}
```

I have this function 7 times with 8 sections that have an ID which is generated via

```
<div id="post-<?php
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            echo $tag->name . ' '; 
        }
    }
?>" class="col-md-4 no-pad containerhover">
```

Currently when I click a button, it hides or shows the content of post-Print

I want it to hide/show the content of the 7 other sections I have, so post-Print is there all the time.

I think there should be some way to hide every DIV with a class except for if they have the specified ID.

Comment: What do the generated IDs look like?

Comment: HTML `id` attribute values should [not contain any spaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: according to your code,
you will have class="post-tag1 tag2"... don't you mean post-tag1 post-tag2...ect

Comment: You may find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551217/jquery-select-all-elements-of-a-given-class-except-for-a-particular-id..good one

Answer (score 1):

First of all, HTML `id` attributes should [not contain any spaces](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute), so you'll need to adapt your PHP code for that. It is necessary before the following will work:

Focussing on your question: if you want to get to all the `post-` elements, *except* one particular one, `post-Print`, then use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with a smart CSS selector `[id^=post-]:not(#post-Print)`.

Here is a demo:

```js
function showprintdiv() {
    // Iterate over all elements that have an id that starts with "post-",
    // except the one you want to keep visible:
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=post-]:not(#post-Print)');
    Array.from(elems, function (x) {
        if (x.id == 'post-Print') return; // don't touch this one.
        x.style.display = (!x.style.display || x.style.display == 'block')
            ? 'none' : 'block';
    });
}

// Demo: toggle visibility every half second:
setInterval(showprintdiv,  500);
```

```html
<div id="post-Print" class="col-md-4 no-pad containerhover">post-Print</div>
<div id="post-1"     class="col-md-4 no-pad containerhover">post-1</div>
<div id="post-2"     class="col-md-4 no-pad containerhover">post-2</div>
<div id="post-3"     class="col-md-4 no-pad containerhover">post-3</div>
```

Comment: Could you give me some feedback? Did this answer your question?